# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages kali Linux 2020

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade, mono

So I am running the latest version of kali Linux. I was previously using the 2019 version of kali which had no issue but after updating, I gave command `apt install mono-devel mono-complete mono-dbg ca-certificates-mono ca-certificates-mono` but it shows

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgdiplus : Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.***
```

After reading some articles about it I gave command `apt-get update && upgrade` but it was showing 35 was not upgraded so i gave command `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` and after that i also gave so I gave command `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

and still if i give `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` 18 are not upgraded and shows

```
The following packages have been kept back:
crackmapexec gcc-10-base lib32gcc-s1 lib32stdc++6 libatomic1 libcc1-0 libgcc-s1
libgfortran5 libgomp1 libitm1 liblsan0 libobjc4 libquadmath0 libstdc++6 libtsan0
libubsan1 linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64
```

can not fix it please help

Comment: if you added things (repositories, packages) not from Kali, you should mention it. Else, using upgrade nevers attempt to remove packages. Using dist-upgrade will evict some to allow upgrading more important ones. so you should try dist-upgrade but apply common sense: if dist-upgrade tells you it will remove a lot of them rather than a few, don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

l faced the same problem and the cause was that l had chosen the wrong type of operating system under the mono offical site. Kali Linux is a Debian based Linux Distribution
so here is a quick way to solve it

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https dirmngr gnupg ca certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF

echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list

sudo apt update
```

then after hre is the last option

```
sudo apt install mono-devel
```

Comment: And that's a really good way to break your Kali system. See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/ and search for "Non-Kali Repositories"